# the css animation for <path> element in SVG is not working for mozilla

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations, vendor-prefix

I just wanted to animate the **path** element of the **SVG** in my HTML. It's working fine in chrome but not in **Mozilla**. I have tried some of the vendor prefixes that I have known like **-moz-**, but it's not working yet. The SVG is showing up as in HTML but the problem is with animations only.

```
.hamburger.svg-cross .svg-navbar path:last-child
{
  d: path("M 16.840205,269.8084 186.17353,267.73425");
  animation: .5s svg-navbaractivel forwards;
}
@keyframes svg-navbaractivel {
  0%
  {
    d: path("M 16.840205,269.8084 186.17353,267.73425");
  }
  50%
  {
    d: path("m 16.840207,204.23424 169.333323,1e-5");
  }
  100%
  {
    d: path("M 16.840205,269.8084 186.17353,140.73425");
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to use SMIL if you want to do animations in Firefox. Note that I think Chrome's implementation is non-standard so even if Firefox did support CSS animation of paths it would not use Chrome's syntax.